# How to play HTML5 Video progressively from mysql database without completely downloading it

Tags: php

Am trying to play a .MP4 file stored in a MySQL DB using html5 video. Am able to get it to play, but the problem is it will first download everything from the database before it starts playing. When test online it takes almost forever before the video starts playing. This doesn't behave the same when you are playing the video as a file from a filesystem. Playing from a file plays progressively as its downloading. Is there anyway i can get its to play as is a filesysem.

Your help will be highly appreciated.

Below is the PHP code that does the retrieval from the database with the appropriate headers.

```
        $size   = $meta_object->video_file_size;                     // File size
        $length = $size;                             // Content length
        $start  = 0;                                 // Start byte
        $end    = $size - 1;                         // End byte

        header('Content-type: video/mp4');
        header("Accept-Ranges: bytes");
        if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_RANGE'])) {

            $c_start = $start;
            $c_end   = $end;

            list(, $range) = explode('=', $_SERVER['HTTP_RANGE'], 2);
            if (strpos($range, ',') !== false) {
                header('HTTP/1.1 416 Requested Range Not Satisfiable');
                header("Content-Range: bytes $start-$end/$size");
                exit;
            }
            if ($range == '-') {
                $c_start = $size - substr($range, 1);
            }else{
                $range  = explode('-', $range);
                $c_start = $range[0];
                $c_end   = (isset($range[1]) && is_numeric($range[1])) ? $range[1] : $size;
            }
            $c_end = ($c_end > $end) ? $end : $c_end;
            if ($c_start > $c_end || $c_start > $size - 1 || $c_end >= $size) {
                header('HTTP/1.1 416 Requested Range Not Satisfiable');
                header("Content-Range: bytes $start-$end/$size");
                exit;
            }
            $start  = $c_start;
            $end    = $c_end;
            $length = $end - $start + 1;
            header('HTTP/1.1 206 Partial Content');
        } 
        header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
        header("Content-Range: bytes $start-$end/$size");

        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)){                
            extract($row);
            echo $video_file_data;
        }
        header("Content-Length: ".$length);
```

Here is what works for the filesystem approach:

```
    $fpath = "tmp_video/sugarcane.mp4";
    $fp = fopen($fpath, 'rb');

    $size   = filesize($fpath);                  // File size
    $length = $size;                             // Content length
    $start  = 0;                                 // Start byte
    $end    = $size - 1;                         // End byte

    if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_RANGE'])) {

        $c_start = $start;
        $c_end   = $end;

        list(, $range) = explode('=', $_SERVER['HTTP_RANGE'], 2);
        if (strpos($range, ',') !== false) {
            header('HTTP/1.1 416 Requested Range Not Satisfiable');
            header("Content-Range: bytes $start-$end/$size");
            exit;
        }
        if ($range == '-') {
            $c_start = $size - substr($range, 1);
        }else{
            $range  = explode('-', $range);
            $c_start = $range[0];
            $c_end   = (isset($range[1]) && is_numeric($range[1])) ? $range[1] : $size;
        }
        $c_end = ($c_end > $end) ? $end : $c_end;
        if ($c_start > $c_end || $c_start > $size - 1 || $c_end >= $size) {
            header('HTTP/1.1 416 Requested Range Not Satisfiable');
            header("Content-Range: bytes $start-$end/$size");
            exit;
        }
        $start  = $c_start;
        $end    = $c_end;
        $length = $end - $start + 1;
        fseek($fp, $start);
        header('HTTP/1.1 206 Partial Content');
    }
    header("Content-Range: bytes $start-$end/$size");
    header("Content-Length: ".$length);
    header('Content-type: video/mp4');
    header("Accept-Ranges: bytes");

    $buffer = 1024 * 8;
    while(!feof($fp) && ($p = ftell($fp)) <= $end) {

        if ($p + $buffer > $end) {
            $buffer = $end - $p + 1;
        }
        set_time_limit(0);
        echo fread($fp, $buffer);
        flush();
    }

    fclose($fp);
```

Comment: MySQL is *not* the right place to store video.

Comment: RTLM: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substr  and then after you're done reading that, sit back and try to justify to yourself why storing video in a db sounds like a good idea.

Comment: @josh3736 Good point. Just because you can, doesn't mean you should.

Comment: also, you're using mysql_* functions. which are deprecated. Bad boy! Bad boy!!

Comment: Thanks everyone for your comment, will implement that then

Answer (score 2):

Don't store the video in the db. Store it on the file system, with its location in the db. When you point the video element to its URI you will then be able to take advantage of progressive download. This will also keep your db smaller and faster.

Comment: Thanks for your comment laurence, noted.